# Bottom views of the xml layout are not showing up

Tags: java, view, android-linearlayout

This is my register layout. The views which are below password i.e spinners,buttons are not showing up in my phone but its showing up in the emulator...My emualtor is based on nexus 7 whereas my phone is samsung grand..I m wondering what is happening there..Is something wrong in my code.
please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
     >
 <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:src="@drawable/topimg" /> 
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000750"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/register_error"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/fname"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:hint="@string/name"
     ></EditText>

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15dp"
   android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/lname"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:hint="@string/lname"
     ></EditText>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15dp"
   android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/uname"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:hint="@string/username"
     ></EditText>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15dp"
   android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:hint="@string/semail"
     ></EditText>

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15dp"
   android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/pword"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:password="true"
     ></EditText>
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select"   
        android:entries="@array/level_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/level_prompt" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
     />
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/class_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/class_prompt"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF" 
        />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Enroll"   
    android:id="@+id/register" 
    android:background="#589700"
     ></Button>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Back To Login"   
    android:id="@+id/bktologin" 
    android:background="#589700"
     ></Button>

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the height of your inner linear layout is more than the screen size. To solve this problem, you can add a extra scroll view and put this linear layout to the scroll view.